# Creating an XCode project from the command line?

Tags: xcode, command-line, project, creation

I get a new project coming across my desk on an hourly basis.  They all adhere to a very strict format, so it isn't terribly difficult to create a new project from scratch every time, but it is something that I should be able to do from a script that just constructs and builds the entire project.  It would save me a helluva lot of time to have this automated.

The actual build is already done by automated, scripted systems.  I just need to be able to build the project - either from scratch or from a template - each time I go to do the build.

Answer (score 0):

[Rucola](http://rucola.rubyforge.org/) does something like this for RubyCocoa applications. You may be able to modify it or use the same techniques for the project structure you need.